# Was Barry Allen ever mentioned in the Justice League Cartoon

Tags: dc, dc-animated-universe, justice-league, justice-league-unlimited

In both Justice League and Justice League Unlimited, was Barry Allen ever mentioned?

After re-watching most of Justice League Unlimited again recently, Hal Jordan appeared in "The Once and Future Thing" part 2, due to the time skip, but don't remember any mention of Barry.

Comment: Well, Flash in Justice League is Wally West (as clear during the Thanagarian invasion). Will have to check this thing :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like Hal, he doesn't appear in the DCAU, but he was referenced directly and indirectly:

> - A police detective in the Justice League episode "The Brave and the Bold" has a passing resemblance to Barry Allen, acting as the "good cop" during the Flash's interrogation.
> - In the Justice League Unlimited episode "Flash and Substance", the Wally West Flash mentions his uncle "flying in" to attend the dedication of a Flash Museum.
> - There is also another character in the same episode who is Wally's teacher at the forensic lab and bears a resemblance to Barry.
> - Wally has many of Barry Allen's story elements, such as his origin, job, city, foes, and status as being the first scarlet speedster and co-founding the Justice League.
> - In part 1 of the episode "The Brave and the Bold" when the Flash goes into a comatose state he has some strange dreams; in one he has gained so much weight that he is too fat to run, a homage to the Silver Age issue of The Flash #115, and in another he has a giant head, a nod to another Silver Age comic, The Flash #177.

[- Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flash_(Barry_Allen)#Animation_2)

You might already know that Hal and Barry were dead in comics during the DCAU start and run.